# Google Drive API C# Name of application does not change

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to auth with Google Drive account using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet.
But when I change ApplicationName I still see this:
[image: Want to change this text]

Can you tell me how to access this field?
Thanks!

edit:
To be more precise I changed this line:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the name of the application on the **consent screen**, you will need to change it from the corresponding *Google Cloud Project*.

So, for example, when you click on *Enable the Drive API*, you can click on the *API Console* link which will redirect you to the corresponding project.

[image]

Afterwards, you will have to go to *OAuth consent screen* > *Edit app* and change the name from the *Application name* field:

[image]

And after saving the changes, this is how it will look like:

[image]